# xparse error: "kernel/missing-colon" when defining a new command using cs_new:Nn

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

I'll simply show what happens:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSOf0.png]

The documentclass definition is elsewhere on the file. I'm using TeXnicCenter, so interactive mode is not an option.

Comment: `\cs_new:Nn \hello:{hello}` or even better: `\cs_new_nopar:Nn \hello:{hello}` -- All `\cs....` defined macros need a `:` after the command name, regardless whether there's a parameter list or not. Of course, using `\hello:` outside the `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` region won't work unless wrapped in an importer macro

Comment: And please don't post such screenshots only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple errors:

The `expl3` naming convention clearly says (see section 3.2 in the `expl3` manual, [link to manual](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf), [archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20240326114310/https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf)):

> 3.2 Formal naming syntax

> We shall now look in more detail at the syntax of these names.

> A function name in LATEX3 will have a name
> consisting of three parts:

> `\<module>_<description>:<arg-spec>`

This means that the `:` is not optional but mandatory, even for a macro having no arguments at all. The `module` and `description` content are 'arbitrary' in the sense that they should be unique and follow the usual naming conventions.

The `:` has been introduced also to make a clear separation between a `function` and a `variable` like `\l_tmpa_seq` etc.

So use `\cs_new:Nn \hello_internal: {...}` or `\cs_new_nopar:Nn \hello_internal: {}` (which used to be recommended for macros having no argument).

Another issue is that `\hello:` is not accessible outside of the `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` region, since `\hello:` would be interpreted as `\hello` followed by a `:` token, but `\hello` is no defined command here.

To access the features of `expl3` some 'wrapper' (or 'importer') macros have to be defined.

There is however the possibility to use 'ordinary' macro names in `expl3` to, having the `p` syntax:

Short example:

```
\cs_new:Npn \mynicecommand #1#2 { Foo~from~#1~and~#2 }
```

Which approach is used depends on the actual needs (and preferences).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_nopar:Nn \hello_internal: {hello}
\cs_new:Nn \helloother_internal: {hello~other}


\newcommand{\hello}{%
  \hello_internal:
}

\newcommand{\helloother}{%
  \helloother_internal:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\hello

and

\helloother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need to comment the line endings, of course. But isn't `xparse` recommended for wrappers? You load it but don't use it (except for `expl3` itself).

Comment: @cfr: I use % in my personal `expl3` codes as starter of explanatory comments for myself, so I stick to this manner here (even if there no comments). And regarding using `\newcommand` instead of `xparse` macros: I think I was about to change later on.